# Will the ants eat my fruit?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In **Animal Crossing: New Leaf**, I have *perfect peaches* scattered around my entire town. On different occasions, I spot an army of ants swarming around a *perfect peach*. Will they eventually eat the peach or make it disappear?

Comment: The peach was probably actually a _rotten_ peach - the last harvest on a Perfect tree will always be two perfect fruits and a rotten one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I left a turnip out for a few weeks, it rotted (as turnips do) and attracted ants & flies. In short, they did not consume it.

So no, ants & flies won't eat food you leave behind.

Comment: The same applies to candy.  I've never had candy disappear, despite seeing ants on it several times.